# MySQL: Replace a column's values with values in a new table that are closest

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-update, closest

I have two tables like so:

`Table1 (ID, Kilometers, Depth)`
`Table2 (ID, Kilometers, Depth)`

```
Sample Data:
Table 1
1, 0.001, 10
2, 0.002, 11
3, 0.003, 11

Table 2
1, 0.001, 10
2, 0.003, 12
3, 0.004, 15
```

I need to replace the depth in table 1 with the depth in table 2 according to its Kilometers value.

However, there may not be a kilometers value in table2 for everyone in table 1. So i need to get the closest value (by kilometer) and use its depth in the replace.

I was hoping for a single SQL statement to acheive this. 
Just a straight replace would be like:

```
UPDATE T1, T2 SET T1.Depth = T2.Depth WHERE T1.Kilometers = T2.Kilometers
```

Any way i can adapt this to get the closest value?

Comment: Hint: Closest = where absolute value of the difference is at a minimum. SQL conveniently has `ABS`, `-` and `MIN`.

Comment: Which record in table 2 is closest to record 2 in table 2?

Comment: "either one is fine" is never a good spec for writing SQL. SQL usually wants you to be precise.

Comment: understood, the answer can be precise in either of the directions. I am just trying to model the problem i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple and does what you want:

```
UPDATE table1 SET depth = (
     SELECT depth FROM table2 
     ORDER BY (ABS(table1.kilometers-table2.kilometers)) ASC 
     LIMIT 1
);

-- Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table1;
+----+------------+-------+
| id | kilometers | depth |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |      0.001 |    10 |
|  2 |      0.002 |    10 |
|  3 |      0.003 |    12 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tbl1
inner join (
    select tbl1.id,
        (
            select id
            from tbl2
            order by abs(tbl2.Kilometers - tbl1.Kilometers) asc
            limit 1
        ) AS tbl2id
    from tbl1
) X
    on tbl1.id = X.id
inner join tbl2
    on tbl2.id = X.tbl2id

set tbl1.depth = tbl2.depth;
```

Note: `tbl1` and `tbl2` are the two table names. `X` is an alias given to the subquery that determines the closest match per `tbl1.id`. `tbl2id` is the `id` from tbl2 that is closest to each `tbl1.id`, aliased in the subquery.

Comment: hmm, couldnt get this working - what exactly is "tbl2id" and "X"

Comment: @simon comment added to answer